# Turning on color syntax highlighting in Emacs

Tags: emacs, colors, syntax-highlighting

I recently installed Emacs 24.3.93.1 on Cygwin. When I first opened code in it, I got a sort of black-and-white syntax highlighting - keywords were white, function names in declarations were black on a white background, and generic code was grey.

I would like to get Emacs to use full color for syntax highlighting, but have not been able to figure out how to turn it on. Googling has mostly found outdated stuff; things like turning on `font-lock-mode`, which has been enabled by default since 22.1. Right now, my .emacs.d/init.el file contains this code relevant to highlighting:

```
(setq font-lock-auto-fontify t)
(add-hook 'find-file-hooks (lambda () (font-lock-mode 1)))
```

I found these snippets from websites that claimed to tell you how to enable syntax highlighting, but nothing I've tried, including the lines above, has changed anything.

Emacs seems to be analyzing syntax, but it is not using colors to show it. Does anyone know how to force it to use colors?

Comment: Emacs-NN.MM.9X are pretest versions, which should only be used when they're fresh (during the pretest).  Do yourself a favor and use the 24.4 release instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs was not using colors because the `TERM` environment variable was set to `vt100`. Changing it to `xterm` solved the problem.